# How to change pandas column properties with dict comprehension?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dict containing multiple dataframes like so:

```
d = {1 : df1, 2: df2}
```

Now I want to use dict comprehension to change the data type of a column in each dataframe.

That is I want to do this in one line:

```
d[1].loc[:,'col1'] =  d[1].loc[:,'col1'].dtype['float']
d[2].loc[:,'col1'] =  d[2].loc[:,'col1'].dtype['float']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a dictionary to `pandas.DataFrame.astype`

```
d = {k: v.astype({'col1': float}) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need:

```
def myFunc(df, col):
   df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
   return df

dict_ = dict(zip(dict_.keys(),[myFunc(df, 'col1') for df in dict_.values()]))
```

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':['10.4','1.9']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':['101.4','11.9']
})

dict_ = {
    1:df1,
    2:df2
}

print(dict_[1].dtypes)
```

Output:

```
col1    object
dtype: object
```

Then,

```
def myFunc(df, col):
    df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
    return df

dict_ = dict(zip(dict_.keys(),[myFunc(df, 'col1') for df in dict_.values()]))
```

Now,

We do,

```
print(dict_[1].dtypes)
```

Output:

```
col1    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
for k in d:
    d[k]['col1'] = d[k]['col1'].astype('float')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {key:df['col1'].astype('float') for (key, df) in d.items()}
```

Example:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['11.1','1.1']})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['22.2','2.2']})
>>> d = {'1': df1, '2': df2}
>>> d['1'].dtypes
col1    object
dtype: object
>>> d = {key:df['col1'].astype('float') for (key, df) in d.items()}
>>> d['1'].dtypes
dtype('float64')
```

Comment: It returns the error:
"KeyError: 'There are no fields in dtype object."

Comment: @AVL, it works fine for me. Maybe I was using `dtype` similar to the question but I have edited it to `astype` already.